# How do I check ID inputs for duplicates?

Tags: python

I have an inventory program that works 100% but when adding a new item in inventory. How do I make sure the ID number isn't a duplicate to another item already in inventory? The inputs for this are located in the function add_one_item. Please ask questions for more details if need be thank you for your time.

Part of code affected:

```
import os

class Inventory:
    def __init__(self):
    #AT LAUNCH GROUPS AND LOADING FUNCTION
        self.ID = []
        self.item = []
        self.qty = []
        self.load()

def add_one_item(inventory):
    #ADDING PROMPT AND ERROR CHECKING
    print('Adding Inventory')
    print('================')
    while True:
        try:
            new_ID = int(input("Enter an ID number for the item: "))
            new_name = input('Enter the name of the item: ').lower()
            assert new_name.isalpha(), "Only letters are allowed!"
            new_qty = int(input("Enter the quantity of the item: "))
            inventory.add(new_ID, new_name, new_qty)
            break
        except Exception as e:
            print("Invalid choice! try again! " + str(e))
            print()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try if statement `if new_ID in class_variable ID:` print something or do the thing that you want and store a variable of the class in the `add_one_item` so you call the the values in the class `inventory`.

Comment: Is there a way to compare it with the inventory list that the items are added to?

Comment: If `inventory.add` appends to the three lists, then `if new_ID in inventory.ID:`

Comment: Thank you Dan that worked! if you write that in answer. I will accept this as the official answer